# Log-rotate delete original file after compressing

Tags: linux, logrotate, log-rotation

I have following files in my someDir:

```
blacklistadm.out00009 blacklistadm.out00008 blacklistadm.out00007 blacklistadm.out00010 blacklistadm.out00025
```

I have following log rotation pattern in /etc/logrotate.d/:

```
someDir/blacklistadm.out*[0-9]{
    weekly
    missingok
    compress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                rm -f someDir/blacklistadm.out*[0-9]
        endscript
}
```

When the log rotation script is run, it is somehow deleting all the files in someDir. What I want is to .gz all the files and after compressing delete the original file. I don't want to delete the .gz files.

Answer (score 0):

The files are being deleted because your globbing is being used incorrectly.

> blacklistadm.out*[0-9]

literally expands to any file starting with "blacklistadm.out" followed by any sequence of 0 or more characters, ending with a single character within the defined range of 0-9.

This is globbing on to everything obviously, because all your files start with "blacklistadm.out" and end in a number, so when you run your postrotate script with an identical glob you are matching everything in that directory and deleting it.

Comment: @parttimeturle That is fine if it is deleting all these files, my question actually is why it is also deleting the .gz files created after compression.

Comment: @DhruvPandey Show us the contents of your /etc/logrotate.conf file